# How to use datetime.time to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have list of timestamps in the format of HH:MM:SS and want to plot against some values using datetime.time. Seems like python doesn't like the way I do it. Can someone please help ?

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# random data
x = [datetime.time(12,10,10), datetime.time(12, 11, 10)]
y = [1,5]

# plot
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

*TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number*
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using python2?

Comment: yes, I am running the exam same code on python 2.7.2

Comment: you need to use a function called "plot_date" in matplot lib. And you need to convert those datetime objects to matplotlib dates.

Comment: what version of matplotlib?

Comment: >>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.0.1'
>>>

Comment: That is ancient, upgrade and you will have no issue, `pip install -U matplotlib`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574088/plotting-time-in-python-with-matplotlib

Comment: @budder, that question is 6 years old, the OP is using a release from 2011, they should be upgrading.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham         Updated matplotlib to latest 1.4.3 but still seeing the same error. Anything else I may be missing ? Does that same code works for you ?

Comment: Yes but using python2

Comment: ok. I also moved to python 2.7.10. still it doesn't work.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what is your python version ?

Comment: 2.7.9, works perfectly for me

Comment: python 2.9 doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

It is still valid issue in Python 3.5.3 and Matplotlib 2.1.0.

A workaround is to use `datetime.datetime` objects instead of `datetime.time` ones:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# random data
x = [datetime.time(12,10,10), datetime.time(12, 11, 10)]
x_dt = [datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), t) for t in x]
y = [1,5]

# plot
plt.plot(x_dt, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

By deafult date part should not be visible. Otherwise you can always use DateFormatter:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H-%M-%S'))
```

Comment: In my case, this results in the lines for different days being plotted *next* to each other instead of overlapping.  How can I get all lines within the same 24h range?

Answer (score 2):

### Well, a two-step story  <sub>to get 'em PLOT really nice</sub>

[image]

### **Step 1**: prepare data into a proper format

from a `datetime` to a `matplotlib` convention compatible **`float`** for dates/times

---

As usual, **devil** is hidden in detail.

**`matplotlib`** dates are ***almost*** equal, but **not** equal:

```
#  mPlotDATEs.date2num.__doc__
#                  
#     *d* is either a class `datetime` instance or a sequence of datetimes.
#
#     Return value is a floating point number (or sequence of floats)
#     which gives the number of days (fraction part represents hours,
#     minutes, seconds) since 0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, *plus* *one*.
#     The addition of one here is a historical artifact.  Also, note
#     that the Gregorian calendar is assumed; this is not universal
#     practice.  For details, see the module docstring.
```

So, highly recommended to re-use their "own" tool:

```
from matplotlib import dates as mPlotDATEs   # helper functions num2date()
#                                            #              and date2num()
#                                            #              to convert to/from.
```

---

### Step 2: manage axis-labels & formatting & scale (min/max) as a next issue

`matplotlib` brings you arms for this part too.

Check [**code in this answer for all details**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32728754/3666197)

Answer (score 1):

I came to this page because I have a similar issue.  I have a Pandas DataFrame `df` with a `datetime` column `df.dtm` and a data column `df.x`, spanning several days, but I want to plot them using `matplotlib.pyplot` as a function of **time of day**, *not* date and time (datetime, datetimeindex). I.e., I want all data points to be folded into the same 24h range in the plot.  I can plot `df.x` vs. `df.dtm` without issue, but I've just spent two hours trying to figure out how to convert `df.dtm` to `df.time` (containing the time of day without a date) and then plotting it.  The (to me) straightforward solution **does not work**:

```py
    df.dtm = pd.to_datetime(df.dtm)
    ax.plot(df.dtm,  df.x)
    # Works  (with times on different dates; a range >24h)

    df['time'] = df.dtm.dt.time
    ax.plot(df.time,  df.x)
    # DOES NOT WORK: ConversionError('Failed to convert value(s) to axis '
    matplotlib.units.ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units:
    array([datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(0, 5), etc.])
```

This **does work**:

```py
    pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()  # Needed to plot Pandas df with Matplotlib
    df.dtm = pd.to_datetime(df.dtm, utc=True)     # NOTE: MUST add a timezone, even if undesired
    ax.plot(df.dtm,  df.x)
    # Works as before
    
    df['time'] = df.dtm.dt.time
    ax.plot(df.time,  df.x)
    # WORKS!!! (with time of day, all data in the same 24h range)
```

Note that the differences are in the first two lines.  The first line allows better collaboration between Pandas and Matplotlib, the second seems redundant (or even wrong), but that doesn't matter in my case, since I use a single timezone and it is not plotted.