# Reading a time list and make a plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am reading the text file that has two columns in the next format:

```
20120101 5.6
20120102 5.3
20120103 5.4
...
```

Where the first column is `YYYYMMDD` yearmonthday and the second is a magnitude.

Here's what I am doing so far:

```
file = open('junk.txt','r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

Magnitude=[]
Year=[]

for line in lines:
    p=line.split()

    Year.append(str(p[0]))
    Magnitude.append(float(p[5]))

year = np.array(Year, dtype='datetime64[Y]')
mag=np.array(Magnitude)

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax2.plot_date(year, Cmag, color='k',linestyle='-',linewidth=2.0)
ax2.set_xlabel('Number of Events')
ax2.set_ylabel('Cumulative Moment')
```

However the format of the **`x`** axis (time) is not correct. I would like to display the time in the format: **`yyymm`** in the `x` axis.

Here's a link with my output (figure):

https://drive.google.com/a/ucsc.edu/file/d/0B3Y1nDlkfy2VNjlBS2FrT0ZRWW8/view?usp=sharing

You can see that time isn't recognized correctly.

Comment: How is `ax2` defined?

Comment: could you edit your question to include the output you want versus the output you are getting? this will help to answer your question.

Comment: fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1,1,1)

Comment: Tried to upload your picture into post, but Google-Drive side settings are not allowing to do that: [**Option 1: Set permission** to open the file] as either **[public]** or **[anyone who owns the link]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **`matplotlib`** has a special datetime value ( processing & formatting )

So, a two-step story  <sub>to get 'em PLOT really nice</sub>

[image]

### **Step 1**: prepare data into a proper format

from a `datetime` to a `matplotlib` convention compatible **`float`** for dates/times

---

As usual, **devil** is hidden in detail.

**`matplotlib`** dates are ***almost*** equal, but **not** equal:

```
#  mPlotDATEs.date2num.__doc__
#                  
#     *d* is either a class `datetime` instance or a sequence of datetimes.
#
#     Return value is a floating point number (or sequence of floats)
#     which gives the number of days (fraction part represents hours,
#     minutes, seconds) since 0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, *plus* *one*.
#     The addition of one here is a historical artifact.  Also, note
#     that the Gregorian calendar is assumed; this is not universal
#     practice.  For details, see the module docstring.
```

So, highly recommended to re-use their "own" tool:

```
from matplotlib import dates as mPlotDATEs   # helper functions num2date()
#                                            #              and date2num()
#                                            #              to convert to/from.
```

---

### Step 2: manage axis-labels & formatting & scale (min/max) as a next issue

`matplotlib` brings you arms for this part too.

```
from matplotlib.dates   import  DateFormatter,    \
                                AutoDateLocator,   \
                                HourLocator,        \
                                MinuteLocator,       \
                                epoch2num
from matplotlib.ticker  import  ScalarFormatter, FuncFormatter

aPlotAX.xaxis.set_major_formatter( DateFormatter( '%Y%m' ) )  # OUGHT WORK
```

Check [**code in this answer for all details**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32728754/3666197)