# Plotting timestamps in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe which contains a column called "order.timestamp" - a list of timestamps for a set of occurrences.

I would like to plot these timestamps on the x-axis of a matplotlib plot and have the dates, hours, seconds etc display as I zoom in. Is this possible?

I have tried using datetime.strptime:

```
date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

for i in range(0, len(small_data)) :

    b = datetime.strptime(small_data["order.timestamp"].iloc[i],date_format)

    small_data = small_data.set_value(i, "order.timestamp", b)
```

Which re-creates the column "order.timestamp" in my pandas dataframe. The column now contains entries like:

```
2017-01-01 12:50:06.902000
```

However, if I now try to plot as normal:

```
fig = plt.figure()

plt.plot(small_data["order.timestamp"], small_data["y_values"])

plt.show()
```

I see an error

```
ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728212/how-to-plot-timestamps-in-python-using-matplotlib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot timestamps in python using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728212/how-to-plot-timestamps-in-python-using-matplotlib)